# Select distinct gives error ORA-01427 - single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a PL/SQL query (SELECT) with some subqueries.
When the first SELECT (main SELECT) in query is without DISTINCT, it doesn't produce any error.
When I add 'DISTINCT' to SELECT statement 
or make such construction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
( query )
```

than it produces error:
"ORA-01427 - single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Is it possible to select distinct rows from query in this case so that there will be no errors?

Whole view:

```
WITH dane AS
(
select
          col,
          col_type,
          kio,
          some2_id,
          CASE
             kioen NVL (x.some_id, s.some_id) < 133
             THEN
                DECODE (der,  5032, 5006,  5033, 5006,  der)
             ELSE
                der
          END
             AS der,
          CASE
             kioen NVL (x.some_id, s.some_id) < 133
             THEN
                DECODE (region,  5032, 5006,  5033, 5006,  region)
             ELSE
                region
          END
             AS region,
          CASE
             kioen NVL (x.some_id, s.some_id) < 133
             THEN
                DECODE (tre,  5032, 5006,  5033, 5006,  tre)
             ELSE
                tre
          END
             AS tre,
          lop,
          CASE
             kioen NVL (x.some_id, s.some_id) < 133
             THEN
                DECODE (tre,  5032, 'KAH',  5033, 'KAH',  something2_id)
             ELSE
                DECODE (tre,
                        5032, 'KAH Non',
                        5033, 'KAH',
                        something2_id)
          END
             AS something2_id,
          NVL (x.some_id, s.some_id) some_id
FROM
((SELECT cols.col,
                  cols.col_type,
                  cols.some2_id,
                  cols.der,
                  cols.region,
                  cols.tre,
                  cols.lop,
                  kio,
                  DECODE (cols.tre, 5006, 'KAH', cga.something2_id)
                     something2_id,
                  cga.some_id
             FROM (SELECT s.typ col,
                          'S' col_Type,
                          some2_id,
                          s.der,
                          region,
                          tre,
                          lop
                     FROM typ s, typ_j sh
                    kioere S.typ = sh.typ
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT kio,
                          'W' col_type,
                          NVL (
                             (SELECT DISTINCT some2_id
                                FROM typ
                               kioere     default_kio = kio
                                     AND dc_id != 'TRY'
                                     AND some2_id <> 'PL'
                                     AND kio_add2 NOT LIKE '%kio'
                                     AND typ NOT BETWEEN 90000 AND 99999
                                     AND typ NOT BETWEEN 6312978
                                                       AND 6312996),
                             kio.some2_id)
                             some2_id,
                          -1 AS der,
                          -1 AS region,
                          -1 AS tre,
                          -1 AS lop
                     FROM kio) cols
                  LEFT JOIN
                  (SELECT cg.something2_id,
                          cgs.some_id,
                          cgd.some2_id,
                          c.country_desc,
                          cgd.tre,
                          a.tre_NAME,
                          cha.lop_NAME
                     FROM z_some cg
                          JOIN z_some_mv cgs
                             ON cg.something2_id = cgs.something2_id
                          JOIN z_some_detail cgd ON cgs.id = cgd.id
                          JOIN country c ON c.some2_id = cgd.some2_id
                          JOIN tre a ON a.tre = cgd.tre
                          JOIN lop cha ON cha.lop = a.lop
                    kioere cgs.active = 'Y') cga
                     ON     cga.tre = cols.tre
                        AND cga.some2_id = cols.some2_id)x
        LEFT JOIN opi s ON x.some_id IS NULL)
)
select distinct * from dane;
```

(I renamed names of tables etc.)

This subquery is problematic:
    (SELECT DISTINCT country_id
                                    FROM store
                                   WHERE     default_wh = wh
                                         AND dc_id != 'WMS'
                                         AND country_id <> 'PL'
                                         AND wh_add2 NOT LIKE '%WH'
                                         AND store NOT BETWEEN 90000 AND 99999
                                         AND store NOT BETWEEN 6312978
                                                           AND 6312996)

Comment: The problem is in the context, where you want to use this SQL. I guess your example SQL (select distinct * from ..) runs perfectly in your database. Provide some more informations about the context of this query.

Comment: Please add the complete query you're running plus sample input.

Comment: Not related but: PL/SQL is *only* used for stored procedures. A `SELECT` statement is never PL/SQL - although it might be used *in* a PL/SQL block.